# pythonの変数をjavascriptで受け取るには？

Tags: javascript, python, python3, json, flask

PythonとFlaskを使ってwebアプリを制作しているのですが、python計算して出てきたデータをjavascriptに渡してそこでさらに計算をさせたいです。

例えばPythonでプログラムを実行して以下のようなデータが出来たとします。
time = [2018, 3, 15, 9, 18]

それをFlaskというpythonのフレームワークは

```
render_template(
                'result.html',
                time=time)
```

のように記述することでhtmlの方にtimeのリスト変数を渡す事が出来ます。

しかしその変数をjavascriptで使用したい場合jsonファイルに変換して渡す方法と
https://code.i-harness.com/ja/q/aa91ba

inputタグに隠しデータとして記述してjQueryで取り出す方法があるとわかりました。

1番目の方法はjsonで配列を記述することはできるのか？
jsonはpythonで言う辞書型でデータが保存されているのをよく見かけるので配列で保存できるのか
わかりません。
記述はflaskで使用しているテンプレートエンジンJinja2を使って
htmlファイルに以下のような記述をすることでPythonからテンプレートエンジンに渡った変数をjsonファイルに変換してjavascriptに渡せると言うものでした。

```
<script>
      var time = {{ time|tojson }};
</script>
```

これをみて思ったのですが、tojsonをなしにすればtimeをそのままjavascriptの変数にリストを代入する事ができると思うのですが現在、実行できる環境がないのでわかりません。2日後にはパソコンが届くので届いたら実行したいと思います。

2番目の方法はinputタグのvalueに配列で保存してそれをjQueryで取り出す方法なのですが
1番目に比べるとスッキリしない感じがするので何か他にいい方法はないでしょうか？

教えて頂けると幸いです。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

flaskにはあまり詳しくないのですが・・・

JSONで配列を扱うことは可能です。なので`time|tojson`でparseできるはずです。

[JSON - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON)

以下は上記のリンク先からの引用です。

> JSON は、オブジェクト、**配列**、数値、文字列、真偽値、そして null をシリアライズする構文です。

Comment: 上手くできました。ありがとうございます！